# In android is it possible to get facebook friends birthday in api v2.2

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In android is it possible to get facebook friends birthday in api v2.2,
i surfed a lot till i didnt get any solutions.

[Fetch friends birthday using facebook graph api v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27924140/3182144)

[Fetching Friend list data from Facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775438/fetching-friend-list-data-from-facebook-api)

Comment: Why do you expect a "solution" if the answers clearly state that it's no longer possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible at all to get friend birthdays since v2.0. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog